# Are there timelike 3D surfaces in special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, definition, causality

I am reading Scharf's 'finite QED' and I am puzzled at the beginning. He first introduces  Minkowski space with $(+,-,-,-)$ signature, and here is a definition I find difficult:

> A three-dimenstional surface $S$ in $M$ is called time-like or space-like if any tangent vector to $S$ is time-like or space-like, respectively.

Of course one can define anything, but to me it seems there cannot be any time-like three dimensional surfaces. Is this right? Or can you provide an example?

Comment: I am with you in this. I can think of timelike 1D surfaces, but as soon as I add a second dimension some of the tangent vectors become spacelike.

Comment: Which page in Scharf?

Comment: @Qmechanic page 8, second edition

Comment: It's page 3 in first edition.

Comment: Scharf is just plain wrong. The natural reading of his definition is "... iff $\forall$ tangent vectors...," but this is wrong for the reason given by the OP: timelike surfaces would not exist. If we change the interpretation to "... iff $\exists$ a tangent vector...," then it's still wrong, because then every timelike surface is also a spacelike surface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to page 9 in [https://web.math.princeton.edu/~aretakis/columbiaGR.pdf](https://web.math.princeton.edu/%7Earetakis/columbiaGR.pdf):

> A hypersurface $H$ is called spacelike, if the normal $N_x$ at each point $x\in H$ is timelike.
>
> A hypersurface $H$ is called null, if the normal $N_x$ at each point $x\in H$ is null.
>
> A hypersurface $H$ is called timelike, if the normal $N_x$ at each point $x\in H$ is spacelike.

In my experience, this is how physicists normally use these words. Scharf's definition seems ambiguous, because if a codimension-one hypersurface in Minkowski spacetime has a timelike tangent vector, then it necessarily also has a spacelike tangent vector. The definitions I quoted avoid this ambiguity by referring to normal vectors instead.

Comment: Great. Thanks. So probably instead of calling it time-like, calling it 'not space-like and not null' would be more appropriate.